# Getting error trying to start rails server on Vagrant vm

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, vagrant

below is the console error message I get when trying to run "rails s" on a vagrant VM. It exits with all this error message, first line being 
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

Not sure what is going on here ...

Thank you so much

---

config\initializers\tire.rb
    subdomain = ""

```
if Rails.env.alpha?
  subdomain = ".alpha."
end

if Rails.env.development?
  Tire.configure { logger 'log/elasticsearch_development.log', :level => 'debug' }
else
  Tire.configure { logger "log/elasticsearch.#{Rails.env.to_s.downcase}.log" }
end

prefix = "org.#{Rails.application.class.parent_name.downcase}#{subdomain}_#{Rails.env.to_s.downcase}"
Tire::Model::Search.index_prefix(prefix)


def get_indices_for_env(prefix)
  aliases = Tire::Configuration.client.get(Tire::Configuration.url + '/_aliases').body
  global_indices = MultiJson.load(aliases).keys

  all_indices = global_indices.select do |index|
    index.start_with? prefix
  end
  all_indices.freeze
end

ALL_INDICES = get_indices_for_env(prefix)
```

---

error message

---

> vagrant@precise32:/vagrant$ bundle exec rails s
>   => Booting WEBrick
>   => Rails 3.2.17 application starting in development on http://x.x.x.x:3000
>   => Call with -d to detach
>   => Ctrl-C to shutdown server Exiting /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in
>   `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in`
>   open'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in
>   `block in connect'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in`
>   timeout'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in
>   `connect'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in`
>   do_start'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in
>   `start'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in`
>   transmit'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in
>   `execute'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/tire-0.6.2/lib/tire/http/client.rb:11:in`
>   get'
>           from /vagrant/config/initializers/tire.rb:20:in `get_indices_for_env'
>           from /vagrant/config/initializers/tire.rb:29:in`'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in
>   `load'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in`
>   block in load'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in
>   `load_dependency'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in`
>   load'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in`
>   each'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in
>   `block in <class:Engine>'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`
>   instance_exec'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
>   `run'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`
>   block in run_initializers'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
>   `each'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`
>   run_initializers'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in
>   `initialize!'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`
>   method_missing'
>           from /vagrant/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
>           from /vagrant/config.ru:3:in`require'
>           from /vagrant/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in`
>   instance_eval'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in
>   `initialize'
>           from /vagrant/config.ru:in`new'
>           from /vagrant/config.ru:in `<main>'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in`
>   eval'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in
>   `parse_file'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in`
>   app'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in
>   `app'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in`
>   wrapped_app'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in
>   `start'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in`
>   start'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in
>   `block in <top (required)>'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in`
>   tap'
>           from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>           from script/rails:6:in`require'
>           from script/rails:6:in `'

Comment: Take a look at the code: 'config/initializers/tire.rb:20' based on the error it is making an http request and failing

Comment: @house9 thanks house9, I edited the original post with the ruby file in config/initializers/tire.rb but not exactly sure what the problem is ... I'm seeing this Rails project for the 1st time, handed down from somebody else through Vagrant.

Comment: Start with commenting out that file and see if you can get rails to start up

Comment: @house9 thanks, commenting out that stupid file worked but now i have another problem though ... maybe I can deal with it on another question but would you have any idea with this? The rails server puts up error that says: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PostsController#homepage

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'posts.status' in 'where clause': SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts`  WHERE `posts`.`status` = 'PUBLISHED' AND `posts`.`post_type` = 'About' AND (title LIKE 'About Ourgoods%') ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1.... I have the database snapshot in a *.sql file, so I guess i have to hook it up

Comment: @house9 never mind, I figured it out, thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like house9 commented above, I basically commented out the entire ruby file that was causing me the problems.

And then I had a problem starting the Rails server because it couldn't find a database. So it threw an ActiveRecord error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PostsController#homepage
>   Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'posts.status' in 'where clause': SELECT
>   posts.* FROM posts WHERE posts.status = 'PUBLISHED' AND
>   posts.post_type = 'About' AND (title LIKE 'About Ourgoods%') ORDER BY
>   created_at DESC LIMIT 1....

After connecting a .sql file that I had to the Rails app (following instructions from: [How do I connect a mysql database file to a local ruby on rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257024/how-do-i-connect-a-mysql-database-file-to-a-local-ruby-on-rails-application)), and running rake db:migrate, I finally got rails s working!